# Optional include in PHP

Tags: php, include, option-type

I have a config file with the general configuration (in a git repo), and a local config file that overwrites configuration properties (ignored in the repo). Right now the local config file is included at the beginning of the config file:

```
include_once 'local_config.php';
```

But I would like the include to be conditional: only do it if the file local_config.php actually exists. I can do a [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138444/using-php-include-during-conditional-statements) without problems, but first I would need to check if the file exists. So I tried get_include_path() but it returns a list of paths, and I would have to parse this list and check for every one.

Another option would be to just call include_once() and suppress the warnings, but it is even messier. Is there a simpler way to do a real optional include in PHP?

Comment: Maybe I am thinking to simple, but a simple `if(file_exists($path)) {` is what you need.

Comment: See my comment below: get_include_path() might return something different than the current directory `.`, in which case I should look there: `if (file_exists($include_path . $path)) {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `file_exists()` predefined PHP function like so:

```
// Test if the file exists
if(file_exists('local_config.php')){
    // Include the file
    include('local_config.php');
}else{
    // Otherwise include the global config
    include('global_config.php');
}
```

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I don't think that is enough. How can I be sure if the include file is in the current directory? Perhaps the general config has been included from a different file which has called set_include_path() to a different directory. In that case I should look there: `if (file_exists($include_path . $path)) {}.` On my local system there are several different paths in `include_path`.

Comment: Then loop through each of the paths with a `foreach` statement. You can also use PHP's `glob` function to list files from a directory. Does this help?

Comment: That is exactly what I described and what I am trying desperately to avoid :)

Comment: If you are testing if the file exists in multiple directories, the best and most efficient method is to use a `foreach` loop! Would you like me to write an example?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use file_exists()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stream_resolve_include_path($filename)` if you have a PHP version higher than 5.3.2

http://php.net/stream_resolve_include_path