# custom error when trying to include/require

Tags: php, include

How to print custom error when trying to include/require a php file ?

This was my idea:

```
<?php 

try{
    include "template/".$_GET['view'].".php"; 
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'some error code'; 
};

?>
```

But, still I'm getting default error if required file don't exist.

Comment: Why not check if file exists first before including. If it doesn't exist, output  your custom error.

Comment: The best solution would be using a language with proper error handling.

Comment: You also need to use some sanity checking on `$_GET['view']`. Otherwise someone can use e.g. `view=../../../../somewhere/evil.file%00` to include another file - possibly one uploaded by the user that contains malicious code.

Comment: Where did you get this idea? It's true that one can "assume" that an exception will be thrown when something goes wrong, but nowhere in the documentation for `include` does it say that it actually works like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decided the comment was worth changing to answer:

Use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to see if file exists.

If it does, include, else echo your custom error message.

Comment: Two words: [race condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition). It's not your fault, but PHP really needs to up its game!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if the file is there before including. That way you can handle the error.

```
<?php

if(file_exists('asd.php')){
    include "asd.php";
}else{
    echo "Oh no! The file doesn't exist!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The include errors are not going to be caught by your try/catch, however, I believe that errors inside the included script would be caught correctly. A better solution would be to use the file-exists function, see this post for an example: [Optional include in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224730/optional-include-in-php)

Once you perform your own verification for the existence for the file you can wrap the executing code in a try catch to ensure errors in that code are caught.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using just `file_exist`. You don't want your visitor to have access to any file on your file-system so I would recommend a white-list; if the file-name is in the white-list, only then display / include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((include "template/".$_GET['view'].".php") != 'OK') {
    echo "My custom error message";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own error Message you can do it like this:

```
<?php
$file = "template/".$_GET['view'].".php";
if ( error_reporting() == 0 ){
    ( @include_once($file) ) OR die("<tt><p><b>ERROR</b> $file file not found!</p>");
}else{
    require_once($file);
}
?>
```

So if there is no error reporting (as most time in productiv enviroment) you can print your own Error Message. If you are in Development Mode (ans error_reporting is on) the you get PHP Error Message!

> **HINT** Never use $_GET Input from user direct for an Include - this is a Black XSS Hole :-D